# WiFi won't stay on after factory reset

Tags: wi-fi, factory-reset

I have PendoPad 7" tablet (PNDP5M7BLK) on Android 5.0.2. My wife reset it using factory reset, and the WiFi won't stay on so I can't connect to internet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try resetting it again? I would try resetting 3 more times before moving on to [this XDA thread](http://androidforums.com/threads/custom-rom-for-pendo-pad.502155/page-2)... if that doesn't work, buy a new tablet!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think I fixed it. I did another factory reset, and tried wi-fi, wouldn't work, tried reboot, didn't work. But I then turned off then turned on, and worked. Thanks for replying!